# Expand command in pgfplots axis options

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, xparse

Depending on a boolean flag, I would like to set axis options like in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{mydebug}   

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfDebugTF}{mm}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{mydebug}}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\setboolean{mydebug}{true}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\IfDebugTF{xmin=5}{xmin=0}]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This does not work, and I think the problem is with expansion.
Can I somehow force the macro expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pgfkeys` tries to expand macros, but `\IfDebugTF` is not fully expandable, so it fails. (In fact, it is not expandable at all, as `\NewDocumentCommand` creates `\protected` macros.) The following would work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\foo{}{xmin=0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[\foo]
    \addplot {x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thus, in order to achieve your objective, you have to

- either define a fully expandable macro containing the desired options
- or, more cleanly, just set the options directly (using `\pgfplotsset`)

before `\begin{axis}`. You could achieve this by

- checking the value of `mydebug` before `\begin{axis}` or
- instead of setting `mydebug`, just setting the options directly (using some helper macro).